Can we pass directory list from find command as argument to another find command and execute md5sum?
I want to list all the directories in present directory and pass those directories as a argument to another find command
The below example will explain it correctly.
$ find . -maxdepth 1 -type d
.
./dir1
./dir2
./dir3
./dir4

$ echo -e "\n" ; find (above directories as argument) -exec md5sum {} +

So that I get checksum values for every files in a folder separately, separated by space.
I think the above example explains the problem correctly Sorry for my bad English and I have very little knowledge on Linux command please forgive me
Thank you in advance.

@ilkkachu it will exclude files directly under ./, I suppose (although isn't there mindepth or something...)

If you're thinking that this will result in all of the files in a directory being passed to a single md5sum, there's no guarantee that will happen. Depending on the path lengths, multiple md5sums might be called for a single directory

@ilkkachu I think the idea is that OP wants a blank lines between each directory.

Can anyone answer how to trim the first directory so that the result will not display first directory example.                      (Md5sum value) ./dir2/dir3/file1             (md5sum value) ./dir1/dir2/dir3/file1 dir1             ( must not be displayed in the output result) thank you

You can do:
find . ! -name . -prune -type d -exec sh -c '
  for dir do
    printf "\n\n"
    find "$dir" -type f -exec md5sum {\} +
  done' sh {} +

(here we quote the } inside the embedded sh code with \ so that {} doesn't appear in there, because with some find implementations, the outer find would substitute it with the directory path even though the {} is not on its own as an argument).
I've also replaced the non-standard  -maxdepth 1 with the standard ! -name . -prune which here is more like -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 in that it skips . (at depth 0) which I suspect is what you would want here.
If using zsh, you can do it without the need for find and with a sorted list of dirs and files:
for dir in *(ND/); do
  print '\n'
  files=( $dir/**/*(ND.) )
  (( $#files )) && md5sum -- $files
done

You could also skip printing the separator on the first run and for directories without regular files:
run=0
for dir in *(NDF); do
  files=( $dir/**/*(ND.) )
  if (( $#files )); then
    (( run++ )) && print '\n'
    md5sum -- $files
  fi
done

Beware on systems that have a limit on the size of the list of arguments that can be passed to a command upon execution (most), executing md5sum might fail if there's a large number of regular-files in (and below) a single directory. You may need to use zargs to work around it. find's -exec cmd {} + does the splitting automatically.

Thank you very much, this perfectly works for me, this is what I needed ☺️☺️

what if I don't want the find command not to display the first directory of the path
